No me autentica correctamente el usuario en el servlet
He estado intentando implementar un login que tenia con JFrame a JSP, sin embargo no he conseguido autenticar el usuario en el servlet, he probado las posibles causas y la curiosidad que observé es que al cambiar if (tipoUsuario!=null) por if (tipoUsuario==null) si me manda al PortalCliente.jsp. Es decir, pareciera que siempre estuviera recibiendo valor null, a pesar de que ya probé que el DAO funcionara con un main de prueba y también verifiqué que el LoginServlet recibiera los datos del formulario login.
Intenté implementar modelo MVC que tenia con la interfaz JFrame lo mas similar posible, ya que ahí si me funciona correctamente.
Acá las clases:
LoginCliente.jsp
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Login Cliente</title>
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="bg-gradient-primary">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-12 col-md-9">
            <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-block bg-login-image"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="p-5">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">¡Bienvenido!</h1>
                                </div>
                                <form class="user" action="LoginServlet" method="POST">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user"
                                               id="exampleInputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                                               name="username" placeholder="Ingresa el usuario o correo..." required/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user"
                                               id="exampleInputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck">
                                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Recuérdame</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" name="accion" value="Ingresar">
                                        Ingresar
                                    </button>
                                    <hr>
                                    <% 
                                        String errorMessage = (String) request.getAttribute("error");
                                        if (errorMessage != null) { 
                                    %>
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                        <%= errorMessage %>
                                    </div>
                                    <% } %>
                                </form>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <a class="small" href="FormCliente.jsp">¿No tienes usuario registrado?</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

LoginServlet.java
package controladorWeb;

import control.ControlPpal;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String usuario = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if (usuario != null && !usuario.isEmpty() && password != null && !password.isEmpty()) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            ControlPpal controlPpal = new ControlPpal();
            String tipoUsuario = controlPpal.autenticarCliente(usuario, password);

            if (tipoUsuario!=null) {
                session.setAttribute("logguedUser", usuario);
                session.removeAttribute("error");
                response.sendRedirect("PortalCliente.jsp");
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("error", "Usuario, contraseña o rol incorrectos");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("LoginCliente.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("error", "Debe completar todos los campos.");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("LoginCliente.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}

ControlPpal.java
package control;

public class ControlPpal {

    public String autenticarCliente(String usuario, String password) {
        ControlCliente controlCliente = new ControlCliente();
        return controlCliente.autenticar(usuario, password); // No se necesita pasar la sesión aquí
    }
}

ControlCliente.java
package control;

import modelo.persistencia.DaoCliente;

public class ControlCliente {

    DaoCliente dc = new DaoCliente();

    public String autenticar(String usuario, String password) {
        return dc.autenticar(usuario, password); // Aquí se llama al DAO para autenticar
    }
}


DaoCliente.java
package modelo.persistencia;

import modelo.entidad.Cliente;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class DaoCliente {

    BD basedatos = new BD();

    public String autenticar(String usuario, String password) {
    String sql = "SELECT nombre FROM usuarios WHERE (nombre = ? OR email = ?) AND password = ? AND idrol = 3";
    
    try (Connection conn = basedatos.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            stmt.setString(1, usuario);
            stmt.setString(2, usuario);
            stmt.setString(3, password);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        
            if (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getString("nombre"); // Retorna el nombre del cliente
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}



Parece que el problema está en que tipoUsuario sigue obteniendo un valor null, así que probablemente el DAO no está encontrando al usuario en la base de datos, o algo en la autenticación falla.
Te sugiero que pruebes:
Revisar que la consulta en DaoCliente funcione bien. Asegúrate de que el usuario y la contraseña que estás pasando existen en la base de datos y que el idrol realmente es 3 (esto puede ser clave). Incluso puedes probar la consulta directamente en la base de datos para confirmar que funciona con esos valores.
Imprimir valores al ejecutar la consulta. Esto te ayudará a ver qué valores llegan a DaoCliente. Justo antes de ejecutar el executeQuery, imprime usuario y password en consola para asegurarte de que llegan bien o en pantalla. También, imprime el resultado de rs.next() para ver si está devolviendo datos o no.
Asegurarte de que la base de datos responde correctamente.
Vale la pena revisar que los permisos en la base de datos y los datos del usuario sean correctos, a veces algo tan básico como la configuración o permisos puede interferir y que la autenticación falle sin razón aparente.
Revisando estos puntos @Willow deberías poder detectar si el fallo está en los valores, en la consulta, o en algo relacionado con la conexión a la base de datos.
Mucha suerte!

Muchas Gracias, tenía un problema con el driver de la base de datos
